# Set value of IDCell to ((value of previous row IDCell) +1)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, setvalue

I have a googlescript which creates a form that allows for existing entries to be edited, or for new entries to be added to a google spreadsheet. If it's a new entry, it takes the field values from the google form and places them into the last row of the google spreadsheet.

```
var lastCell = sheet.getLastRow(); //entry holds value of current last row position
var entry = sheet.getLastRow()+1; //entry holds value of new last row position
var IDCell = sheet.getRange("C"+entry); //IdCell is in column C, last row of table
```

The above code is fine..
The part I am hoping to get some help with is the part where I set IDCell to equal ((IDCell of the previous row) +1)

Something like:

```
IDCell.setValue((sheetData [lastCell][2]) +1);
```

but this gives me errors "Error encounter: cannot read property "2" from undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve on my own:

```
var lastcell = sheet.getLastRow();
var entry = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
var IDCell = sheet.getRange("C"+entry);
var prev_ID = sheet.getRange("C"+lastcell);
var prev_IDV = prev_ID.getValue();
IDCell.setValue((prev_IDV)+1);
```

This might have been obvious to some, but I am very new at JavaScripts so it wasn't immediately clear